# Cannot get Automatic Markdown Compilation working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code, markdown

Using the steps outlined in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown
in step 3 of the [Automatic Markdown compilation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_step-3-run-the-gulp-default-task) section I am not presented with a picker listing the tasks defined in the gulp file.

`gulp -v` produces

> CLI version 3.9.1
>
> Local version 3.9.1

My steps are to this point are:

1. create the gulpfile.js file in the root folder (the folder that
   contains the .vscode folder)
2. copy the contents of the file verbatim from the instructions
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command menu
4. Select `Tasks: Run Tasks`

Here I'm presented only with `task` in the field and `No tasks found`below.

I've tried just copying the contents of what the tasks.json file should look like, according to the instructions, but I can't seem to get the system working where my markdown files are automatically compiling.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post what your `tasks.json` looks like? We cannot help unless you show us some of your code.

Comment: According to the directions you are to either delete the tasks.json file or remove all but the "version": "2.0.0" property. I have tried both ways and neither approach works.

Comment: There is your issue then! You ***NEED*** a `tasks.json` if you want to make use of VS Code's build task functionality.

Comment: I do not see where the tutorial you liked to tells you to delete the `tasks.json` file.

Comment: The second sentence in the second link, step 3, states: You can either delete the tasks.json file or empty it only keeping the "version": "2.0.0" property.

Comment: Then read on... you only delete it to re-add it later on.

Comment: I've tried both ways 1) deleting it 2) removing all the info except for the "version":"2.0.0" property. It seems as though the tasks.json file should be populated with the information in the code block in the second paragraph in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I needed to add the environment variable NODE_PATH targeting the node_modules folder. In my case it was `NODE_PATH=C:\node_modules`.